# Arrows and nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw arrows not necessarily at the end of the line, nor in the middle. I would also like to write a node directly above (or below, or to the right, ...) the arrow.

I saw this question, but it doesn't answer all my questions - first of all, it puts the arrow in the middle of the line. I know I can modify that by playing with `mark=at position 0.5`, but it's very possible that I'd like a certain position in one line, and a different in the other, i.e. use `\draw[mystyle 0.5]` for the middle, `\draw[mystyle 0.75]` for having it three-quarters way through etc.. In addition it doesn't solve the nodes issue.

Can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: Do you mean arrowheads instead of arrows?

Comment: I suppose, yes - I mean the little triangles with no third edge.

Comment: Is this close to your goal? `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
markings,
mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{>},\node[sloped,transform shape,above] {A};}
}
]
  \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (1,2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Well, it's close in the sense that the text does appear next to the arrowhead. It's not precisely what I'm looking for because (1) it sets it as default, i.e. if I just use `\draw` and two points I get that, (2) it sets the text (as "A") and (3) I have no control on the position of the arrow. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The thing is, that once you set the decoration right after the `\begin{tikzpicture}`, it is final - I can no longer change the value `0.4`, nor the text - or can I? Anyway, if I indeed do as you suggested in (1), it works - I can set pretty much whatever I want for every arrow. The only problem is that it is a bit long - but I'll live with that... P.S. is it possible to have two or more arrowheads (and draw only on top of one of them)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on our discussion I think the following style definition does the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[
nodewitharrow/.style 2 args={                
            decoration={             
                        markings,   
                        mark=at position {#1} with { 
                                    \arrow{>},
                                    \node[transform shape,above] {#2};
                        }
            },
            postaction={decorate}
}
]

\draw[nodewitharrow={0.6}{Node text},nodewitharrow={0.2}{Second}] (0,0) -- (4,3) ;
\draw[nodewitharrow={0.75}{\tiny Tiny}] (0,0) (4,0) arc (0:60:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you can apply more than once. If you want to change orientation of the text, you can further define a third argument for extra node options e.g. selecting `above`,`below`,`right`, `left` etc.