# How to place a node in the middle of an arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arc

I think it is a simple question, but I didn't find the answer yet. The code I'm using is the following:

```
\draw[->](1,0) arc(0:-30:1) node[midway]{$30$};
```

But in this way the node is placed at the origin intead of at the middle of the arc.

Note: it must be done with `arc`.

Answer (score 38):

As of 2012-03-01, thanks to Till Tantau, it is now possible to do it straightforwardly with [the cvs version of pgf-tikz](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=142562). It has been included since in the stable version of pgf-tikz.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->](1,0) arc(0:-30:1) node[midway]{$30$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly means csv version - does this mean this option is going to become official at one point?

Comment: @pygmalion yes. The CVS version is the development version that will become one day the official one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Since you are already acknowledged with the CSV version, is it possible to make node in the middle of the arc, but on left or right side of it?  Like [midway] and [midway,swap] when driving lines?  If not, I will open request on TikZ development.

Comment: I am sorry for bothering again, but I still don't understand.  Last official version is 2.10, dated 2012-08-19, which is beyond the time you mentioned above.  And this version still does not provide [midway] solution for the arcs.  Am I missing something?  I just don't get it.

Comment: @Pygmalion You need the cvs version (that is the devel version) of tikz. It's been a long time since the last official release. For the installation, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63982/8425).

Answer (score 18):

The reason why it is shown at the origin is because there is no explicit second coordinate for TikZ to interpolate via `pos`. One solution is to, roughly speaking, parameterize the `arc` path via `markings` library. This is simply a modification of [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/arrows-and-nodes-in-tikz/38556#38556) for marking a path with a node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
arcnode/.style 2 args={                
            decoration={
                        raise=#1,             
                        markings,   
                        mark=at position 0.5 with { 
                                    \node[inner sep=0] {#2};
                        }
            },
            postaction={decorate}
}
]
\draw[->, arcnode={20pt}{$30$} ] (0,0) arc (0:-30:2cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: labelled curve with offset label]

For some reason, when the curved paths become too short(e.g. your example path starts working after `1.095cm` for radius of the arc) it gives a `Dimension too large` error, so probably, there is a detail that I don't know yet here. This is not the case for straight paths.

Comment: When the curved paths become too short, there is a problem with `pgfmath` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20833/how-to-put-a-mark-on-an-arc-tikz-decoration

Comment: @Altermundus Ouch! I remember reading your discussion on your question but forgot it completely. Thanks, for the reminder. I guess there is no easy way out for this.

Comment: But is there anyway to have it push out a given radius away from the curve?

Comment: @Richard You can use `above,left`etc. options in the node to take it out of the curve but I'm not sure if I understand your question. Can you explain it a little more, if possible? If the comment box is not sufficient for it, post a new question and we can have look at it together.

Answer (score 12):

Problem taken from: [Draw centered label above arc in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76363/draw-centered-label-above-arc-in-tikz)

---

This is another approach to this problem. In this way, *there* is another second coordinate.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green] (1,0) arc[radius = 1, start angle=0, end angle=90] node[above] {H} arc[radius = 1, start angle=90, delta angle=90];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonder if there is a way to not have to repeat most of the info for the node.

Comment: @PeterGrill [I tried putting all between the from `arc` to `;` in a macro](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6454502#6454502) but it breaks with a lot of `Missing character: There is no [ in font nullfont!`. The full TikZ command is possible, but then it's an isolated path.

Comment: Might work better as a style, but I don't have enough experience to do those, especially since this one would require a parameter.  Something like @percusse's solution here of using an `arcnode`.  Anyway, this something I need to learn so was just thinking about it.

Answer (score 4):

Major newbie here but here is the way I did it.  I was drawing arcs centered at the origin but seems like it should work for others too.

```
\draw (0.3,0) arc (0:30:0.3) node at (15:0.5) {$\varphi$};
```

Comment: Hi bjd, welcome to the site! That's a nice and pragmatic approach (+1), but I think the question was concerned with finding an automatic way to place the node. By the way, you can format code snippets in a post by selecting the text and then clicking the `{}` button in the editor. Looking forward to seeing you around the site!

Answer (score 3):

This solution does not rely on arc, but may be helpful for people looking for a simple solution to draw a curved line with a centered label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[->] (1,0)  edge  [bend left=20]  node[above] {$30$} (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing "left bend" allows you to adjust the curvature.

Comment: +1 Only this ordering seem to with `curve to`. @Experts in tikz, please correct me if I am wrong.