# How draw part of ring or broken ring in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw something like this using `TikZ`:

[image]

It could be one ring which is broken or it could be different parts of different rings. The text should be also bent (not as shown on the `paint` picture:)

I want to do it with some `TikZ` built in functions, objects.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something to start with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (120:2cm) arc [start angle = 120, end angle=60, radius=2cm] --++(60:1cm) arc [start angle=60, end angle=120, radius=3cm] --++(120:-1cm)--cycle;
\draw[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=this is a text, text align={align=center}}] (120:2.5cm) arc(120:60:2.5cm);

\draw (269:2cm) arc [start angle = 269, end angle=133, radius=2cm] --++(133:1cm) arc [start angle=133, end angle=269, radius=3cm] --++(269:-1cm)--cycle;
\draw[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=this is a text, text align={align=center}}] (269:2.5cm) arc(269:133:2.5cm);

\draw (55:2cm) arc [start angle = 55, end angle=-80, radius=2cm] --++(-80:1cm) arc [start angle=-80, end angle=55, radius=3cm] --++(55:-1cm)--cycle;
\draw[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=this is a text, text align={align=center}}] (55:2.5cm) arc(55:-80:2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update* Command `\drawsector`

I'm not sure to understand your comment but you can always define a command to simplify typping.

Command `\drawsector` has 5 parameters plus 1 optional.

```
\drawsector[draw options]{text radius}{width}{start angle}{delta angle}{text}
```

`text radius` is supose to be text baseline radius and because sector border is shifted around text center, I've (negative) `raised` the text. May be some other decoration can place text verticaly aligned to its center, but I don't know how to do it.

`delta angle` means angular widthness (does exist this word?)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

%\drawsector[]{text radius}{width}{start angle}{delta angle}{text}
\newcommand{\drawsector}[6][]{
    \draw[#1] (#4:{#2-.5*#3}) arc [start angle = #4, delta angle=-#5, radius={#2-.5*#3}]--++({#4-#5}:#3) arc [start angle = {#4- #5}, delta angle=#5, radius={#2+.5*#3}] --cycle;
\draw[decorate,decoration={raise=-3pt, text along path, text=#6, text align={align=center}}] (#4:#2) arc(#4:(#4-#5):#2);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\drawsector{2}{1}{130}{100}{this is my text}

\drawsector[draw=green, thick, fill=green!20]{3.2}{.8}{60}{120}{this is another text}

\drawsector[draw=none, fill=blue!30]{2.5}{2}{180}{40}{text}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your question was how to draw a circular sector around a certain circular text, you can try to use Frédéric's answer to [How to Intersect an arc with a line without calculating the angle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41587/1952)

Comment: I used it, it is what I need. But really there is no package to do it without calulating all angles maually?

Comment: @saldenisov They are not what you want, but may be [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159876/1952) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/how-can-i-produce-a-ring-or-wheel-chart-like-that-on-page-88-of-the-pgf-manu/18105#18105) can help you.

Comment: @saldenisov I've updated my answer, is it better now?

Comment: It is much better^)

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The text in the arcs is given to the key `arc data`. This text is centered in the arc with the key `arc data pos=0.5`.

The gaps between the arcs are obtained with the key `gap polar=5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\wheelchart[
  arc data=\WCvarC,
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=white},
  data=,
  gap polar=5,
  slices style={\WCvarB!50,draw=\WCvarB}
]{%
  1/cyan/text A,
  2/violet/text B,
  4/gray/text C%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```