# Changing font size of a text along path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to put a text in a ring section. I found here an example that perfectly fits my needs:
[How draw part of ring or broken ring in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183848/how-draw-part-of-ring-or-broken-ring-in-tikz)

The problem with it is that when I change text size, e.g. by changing to
`{\large this is a text}`, my `pdflatex` hangs, the last message on the screen is:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
```

Comment: Please post a complete example here. Especially if an answer which works for somebody else doesn't work for you. Which example there did you even use? We have no idea....

Answer (score 18):

Your

```
\large
```

should be inside a | bracket:

```
decoration={text along path, text={|\large|this is a text}, text align={align=center}}
```

For me this works.

Edit: Or you can try to change the default setting:

```
decoration={text along path, 
text format delimiters={<}{>},
text={<\large>this is a text}, text align={align=center}}
```

For me, that one works as well.

Comment: Interesting. Why?

Comment: Nope, for me it doesn't, sorry...

Comment: @tnorgd have you considered installing TeX Live 2015 instead. Might be because of a newer version.

Comment: How can you redefine the path over all tikz objects, so you don't have to manually enlarge?

Comment: This actually works, where in the manual is it explained the use of the vertrical bars to specify font size in this decorator? Did you look at the code? Thanks

Comment: I looked it up, page 657 of the TikZ and PGF manual version 3.1.6a has an example.

Comment: First: thanks!  
But isn't there nothing nicer, than such a special syntax `|...|`? I wonder why there is no key like `decorate options={font=\Large}` or similar....