# How to display a duck or marmot swallowed by a darkhole

Tags: pgfplots, tikzducks, tikzlings

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505833/141947) about representation of a darkhole, how could one represent a `tikzduck` or a `tikzmarmot` being swallowed by it.

**No animal nor being should be harmed in the process.**

I think [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484972/141947) based on non-linear transforms or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114558/141947) using `transform canvas` could help, but I don't know where to start really.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={draw=none},
            tick style={draw=none},
            colormap/Blues,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=50,
            domain=0:360,
            y domain=1:10,
            declare function={darkhole(\r)={-exp(-\r)};
                % added functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
                pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
                pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
            },
            xtick={\empty},
            ytick={\empty},
            ztick={\empty},
        ]
            \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort] {darkhole(y)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "No animal should be harmed" is not a very tough requirement because we are dealing with **beings** here. You need to say "No animal nor being is to be harmed!".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A marmot would only fall in a black hole if it is a wormhole. Other than that, you need to draw the black hole in two stretches, first background, then the passenger(s), and then the foreground.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\makeatletter
\def\blackholetransformation{%
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
\pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\pgf@ya-40*exp(-0.04*abs(\the\pgf@xa))}%
\pgf@y=\myy pt}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\Back
\newsavebox\Front
\sbox\Back{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={draw=none},
            tick style={draw=none},
            colormap/Blues,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=25,
            y domain=1:10,
            declare function={darkhole(\r)={exp(-1)-exp(-\r)};
                % added functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
                pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
                pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
            },
            xtick={\empty},
            ytick={\empty},
            ztick={\empty},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {darkhole(y)};
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {darkhole(y)};  
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox\Front{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={draw=none},
            tick style={draw=none},
            colormap/Blues,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=25,
            y domain=1:10,
            declare function={darkhole(\r)={exp(-1)-exp(-\r)};
                % added functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
                pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
                pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
            },
            xtick={\empty},
            ytick={\empty},
            ztick={\empty},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {darkhole(y)};
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {darkhole(y)};  
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}  
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {-50,-48,...,-8,8,10,...,50}%{-50,-40,...,50}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=nonlinear,transform shape
nonlinear=true]
 \pgftransformnonlinear{\blackholetransformation}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-5,-4) rectangle (5,5);
 \node[scale=2]{\usebox\Back};
 \begin{scope}[xshift={-1cm+\X*1mm},yshift={-1*tanh(\X/10)*4cm-1cm}]
  \marmot
 \end{scope}
 \node[scale=2]{\usebox\Front};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version with slower fall.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\makeatletter
\def\blackholetransformation{%
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
\pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\pgf@ya-60*exp(-0.06*abs(\the\pgf@xa))}%
\pgf@y=\myy pt}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\Back
\newsavebox\Front
\sbox\Back{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={draw=none},
            tick style={draw=none},
            colormap/Blues,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=25,
            y domain=1:10,
            declare function={darkhole(\r)={exp(-1)-exp(-\r)};
                % added functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
                pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
                pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
            },
            xtick={\empty},
            ytick={\empty},
            ztick={\empty},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {darkhole(y)};
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {darkhole(y)};  
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox\Front{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={draw=none},
            tick style={draw=none},
            colormap/Blues,
            data cs=polar,
            samples=25,
            y domain=1:10,
            declare function={darkhole(\r)={exp(-1)-exp(-\r)};
                % added functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
                pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
                pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
            },
            xtick={\empty},
            ytick={\empty},
            ztick={\empty},
        ]
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {darkhole(y)};
          \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,opacity=0,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {darkhole(y)};  
         \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort,
            domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180] 
            {-darkhole(y)}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}  
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {-50,-48,...,50}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={darkhole(\r)=exp(-2.5)-exp(-\r);}]
 \path[use as bounding box] (-5,-6) rectangle (5,7);
 \node[scale=2]{\usebox\Back};
 \begin{scope}
  \clip (-5,6) -- plot[domain=-5:-0.5] ({\x},{25*darkhole(abs(5*\x))})
  -- plot[domain=-0.5:-5] ({\x},{-25*darkhole(abs(5*\x))})
  |- (5,-7)
  -- plot[domain=5:0.5] ({\x},{-25*darkhole(abs(5*\x))}) 
  -- plot[domain=0.5:5] ({\x},{25*darkhole(abs(5*\x))}) |-cycle;
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=nonlinear,transform shape
  nonlinear=true]
   \pgftransformnonlinear{\blackholetransformation}
   \begin{scope}[xshift={-1cm+\X*1mm},yshift={-1*tanh(\X/10)*4cm-1cm}]
    \marmot
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}  
 \node[scale=2]{\usebox\Front};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution !!!

Comment: Wow! I love the deforming effects  :):):)

Comment: I think from our point of view, there would be more deformation.

Comment: @Strawberry The strength of the deformation is controlled by `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\pgf@ya-40*exp(-0.04*abs(\the\pgf@xa))}`. If you increase `40` and/or decrease `0.04`, it becomes more pronounced.

Comment: Gotta love those Marmots!

Comment: How do you run this with WinEdt?

Comment: @CuriousEinstein I am a Mac user and have no idea, sorry. I just compile the code with `pdflatex` and convert it with `convert -density 300 -delay 44 -loop 0 -alpha remove <pdf file> <gif file>`, see the end of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/194703).

Comment: I got the message about tkzmarmots.sty file not there. Where can I download it?

Comment: @CuriousEinstein It is at https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmarmots?lang=en but the by far cleaner way is to use a package manager to update your TeX installation.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions, but how do you use the convert?

Comment: @CuriousEinstein I use it as a command on my console (after installing it from ImageMagick). But I do not know how to use it on windows.

Comment: @CuriousEinstein To use imagemagick on windows you have to add it to your latex path and then you can use the convert feature. I hope this helps.

Comment: Its nice how the marmot slides !! Good job!