# Using LaTeX/TikZ for fractal flower

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractals

I am trying to generate this particular fractal image of a flower, but don't even know where or how to start. Can TikZ be used to generate a "*Phylotactic spiral*"?

I saw it here: https://www.reddit.com/r/FractalPorn/comments/xr17t1/fractal_rose/

and the image looks as given below:
[image: Fractal Image]

It seems like loads of dots, so I began trying with a scatterplot on `pgfplots`, but failed completely. No code worth showing here.

**EDIT:**
How do I put a green-tick to more than one answer? The results you folks have given are astounding!

Comment: I can't see where there's any fractal in that design. It's at most a scaled repetition of the same eight leaves flower. Shouldn't involve any fractal definition.

Comment: Fractal := scaled repetition

Comment: To me it looks like you want what once was called dithering. Here are a few tikz-solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266881/how-can-i-add-stippling-to-elements-of-my-tikz-diagrams . // Se also: https://bartwronski.com/2016/10/30/dithering-part-one-simple-quantization/ + https://www.elopezr.com/dithering-algorithm/ + https://tannerhelland.com/2012/12/28/dithering-eleven-algorithms-source-code.html and many other.

Comment: Hi!  An approach for your image might be the following: 1) Draw the basic quadrilateral (plain color first).  2) Transform it into a `pic` element.  3) Learn how to use the command `($(p)! c! angle: (p)$)` which produces the image of the point `q` through a direct similarity of center `p`, ratio `c`, and angle `angle`. 4) Do some mathematics for one of the spirals and create it with the `pic` and the above similarity.  5) Use a `\foreach` loop to have your eight leaves.  6) Modify the filling of the elementary quadrilateral (in the initial `pic`) to have the desired effect.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Many definitions of a fractal are a bit more strict than that. Otherwise, a line segment would be a fractal, as you can make it by putting together infinitely many line segments end to end, each half the size of the one before.

Comment: To answer your edit: You can't. You should upvote both, but then select @Qrrbrbirlbel's answer. I like it better than mine. :-)

Comment: Seemingly relevant (at bottom):  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524254/14100

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm using [Sandy G's formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661411/16595) here, basically the `.707^<level>` part.

Two approaches:

1. PGF and LuaLaTeX that uses [JLDiaz' great poisson lua script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185423/16595).
2. TikZ and PGFmath that just uses the `rnd` function.

The macro `\pgfpointspiralifdefined` makes sure that coordinates that have been calculated already don't need to have be recalculated.

Instead of the coordinate `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, you can also use the `vertex` anchors of the [kite shape](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.kite) that Sandy G's answer uses (you need to name the nodes of course, e.g. `spiral-\l-\n`).

In both solutions I'm cubing one of the random values so that the points get bunched to one side of the kites.

### PGF + LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\usepackage{jldiaz-poisson}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185423/16595
\usepackage{xcolor} % colorwheel
\definecolor{cw0}{HTML}{9AFF00}\definecolor{cw1}{HTML}{FFA500}
\definecolor{cw2}{HTML}{FF001A}\definecolor{cw3}{HTML}{FF00D9}
\definecolor{cw4}{HTML}{6500FF}\definecolor{cw5}{HTML}{005AFF}
\definecolor{cw6}{HTML}{00FFE5}\definecolor{cw7}{HTML}{00FF25}
\pgfset{
  declare function={
    spiralAngle(\level,\spiral) = \directlua{tex.print(
      180/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/spiral\space N})*\level
     +360/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/spiral\space N})*\spiral)};
    spiralRadius(\level)        = \directlua{tex.print(
      .707^\level*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/spiral\space radius}))};
    xSpread(\n)=\n^3*.8+.1; ySpread(\n)=\n*.8+.1;},
  spiral radius/.initial=5, spiral N/.initial=8}
\newcommand*\pgfpointspiral[2]{% #1 = level, #2 = spiral
  \pgfpointpolarxy{spiralAngle(#1,#2)}{spiralRadius(#1)}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pgfpointspiralifdefined[3]{%
  % if spiral-#2-#3 doesn't exist, define it
  % if it does do nothing
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@spiral-#2-#3}{%
    \pgfcoordinate{spiral-#2-#3}{\pgfpointspiral{#2}{#3}}%
  }{}% and make it an alias for #1
  \pgfnodealias{#1}{spiral-#2-#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfsetxvec{\pgfqpoint{5mm}{0mm}}
\pgfsetyvec{\pgfqpoint{0mm}{5mm}}
\foreach \l in {0,...,6}{
  \foreach \n in {0,...,7}{
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{a}{\l}            {\n}
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{b}{\inteval{\l+1}}{\n}
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{c}{\l}            {\inteval{\n+1}}
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{d}{\inteval{\l-1}}{\inteval{\n+1}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{cw\n}
    \foreach[expand list, evaluate={\xSpread=xSpread(\x);}]
      \x/\y in {\poissonpointslist{1}{1}{.02+.0\l}{10}} {
      \pgfpathcircle{
        \pgfpointlineattime{ySpread(\y)}
          {\pgfpointlineattime{\xSpread}
            {\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{b}{center}}}
          {\pgfpointlineattime{\xSpread}
            {\pgfpointanchor{d}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{c}{center}}}
      }{+.25pt}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
  }
}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

### TikZ + PGFmath

The `\pgfpointspiralifdefined` could have also been implemented by a custom TikZ coordinate system but why bother …

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfset{
  declare function={
    xSpread(\n)=\n^3*.8+.1; ySpread(\n)=\n*.8+.1;},
  spiral radius/.initial=5,
  spiral N/.initial=8}
\newcommand*\pgfpointspiral[2]{% #1 = level, #2 = spiral
  \pgfpointpolarxy{180/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/spiral N})*(#1)
                  +360/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/spiral N})*(#2)}
                  {.707^(#1)*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/spiral radius})}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pgfpointspiralifdefined[3]{%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@spiral-#2-#3}{%
    \pgfcoordinate{spiral-#2-#3}{\pgfpointspiral{#2}{#3}}%
  }{}%
  \pgfnodealias{#1}{spiral-#2-#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=+5mm, y=+5mm]
\foreach \l[evaluate={\Dots=250*.7^\l}] in {0,...,6} {
  \foreach \n in {0,...,7} {
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{a}{\l}            {\n}
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{b}{\inteval{\l+1}}{\n}
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{c}{\l}            {\inteval{\n+1}}
    \pgfpointspiralifdefined{d}{\inteval{\l-1}}{\inteval{\n+1}}
    \fill[radius=+.4pt] foreach[
      evaluate={\xSpread=xSpread rnd; \ySpread=ySpread rnd;}]
      \dot in {0,...,\Dots} {
        ($($(a)!\ySpread!(d)$)!\xSpread!($(b)!\ySpread!(c)$)$)
        circle[radius=+.4pt]};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Simply breathtaking!

Comment: This needs level-dependent `xSpread` and `ySpread` or the [`\pgfpointlineatdistance` macro](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tex.sx/blob/master/661409.tex) to [look even more than OP's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqK9n.png) (fixed separation between kites instead of scaling separation).

Comment: This is beautiful work!

Answer (score 24):

Here is the rose, which uses the `kite` node shape from the tikz library `shapes.geometric`. I leave it to others to fill the nodes with dots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{mykite/.style={inner sep=.1pt, kite, fill=red!30, kite vertex angles=120 and 75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \l in {1,...,12}{
\foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \t using \l*22.5+\n*45, % \t is the angle for node placement
    evaluate=\n as \s using .703^(\l-1), % \s is the scaling factor for the distance from 0 for each level
    evaluate=\n as \c using \s-.01] in {1,...,8} % \c is used to shrink each node just a bit.
    {\node[mykite, rotate=\t, minimum size=\c cm] at (\t-90:{\s*1.38}){};}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To get an 8-vertex rose, the kite vertex angles must differ by 45 (120 and 75 in the code above). You can change `.703` to `(sin((\aaa-45)/2)/sin(\aaa/2))`, where `\aaa` is the larger angle to get variations in the shape. The `1.38` factor needs adjusting as well.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]Test

I tried to make the construction using a `pic` and a helix like curve.  All the computations are hidden in the definition of the `petalPiece` (the `pic` element) which creates a quadrangle; each petal will consist of `\nbQuad` pieces.

There are two global variables: the number of petals and the number of pieces for each petal.  For example, with 9 petals, we get the drawing below.
[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  integer \nbPetals, \nbQuad;
  \nbPetals = 8;
  \nbQuad = 7;
  real \a, \base, \r;
  \a = 360/\nbPetals;  % petal's angle
  \base = 2;  % base of the exponential definig the helix
  \r = .35;  % scaling constant
  function tmpR(\i) {% integer giving a point along the helix
    return {\r*pow(\base, 3.145*\i/\nbQuad)};
  };
}
\tikzset{%
  pics/petalPiece/.style 2 args={% branch number, base point number
    code={%
      \tikzmath{integer \b, \p; \b = #1; \p = #2;}
      \path
      (\p/\nbQuad*180 +\b*\a: {tmpR(\p)}) coordinate (NW)
      ({(\p +1)/\nbQuad*180 +\b*\a}: {tmpR(\p +1)}) coordinate (NE)
      ({(\p +2)/\nbQuad*180 +(\b -1)*\a}: {tmpR(\p +2)}) coordinate (SE)
      ({(\p +1)/\nbQuad*180 +(\b -1)*\a}: {tmpR(\p +1)}) coordinate (SW);
      \foreach \i in {0, .05, ..., .9}{%
        \draw[white, thick, fill=magenta!90, opacity=.05]
        ($(NW)!\i!(SW)$) -- ($(NE)!\i/2!(SE)$) -- (SE) -- (SW) -- cycle;
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \l in {1, 2, ..., \nbPetals}{
    \foreach \i in {-1, 0, 1, 2, ..., \nbQuad}{%
      \path (0, 0) pic {petalPiece={\l}{\i}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```