# Intersection point between line and arc

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using tikzpicture for a long time now and making intersections between lines nicely. Even if I make an intersection between an circle and line works nicely and I also find some threads about that topic online. However, I did not manage to make the intersection between an arc and line. I checked this here ([How to Intersect an arc with a line without calculating the angle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41587/how-to-intersect-an-arc-with-a-line-without-calculating-the-angle)) but they always work with circles and not arcs. The intersection I try to make is as follows:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}

 % Points
 \coordinate (a) at (0,0); 
 \coordinate (b) at (0,4);
 \coordinate (c) at (0,6);
 \coordinate (d) at (4,0);
 \coordinate (e) at (6,0); 

 % Point for analyse line
 \coordinate (f) at (7,7);

 % Lines
 \draw [-] (b) -- node [rotate=90, above] {Symmetry plane} (c); 
 \draw [-] (d) -- node [below] {Symmetry plane} (e);

 % Arcs
 \draw [-, name=R1] (d) arc [radius=4, start angle=0, end angle=90];
 \draw [-] (e) arc [radius=6, start angle=0, end angle=90];

 \path[name=L1] (a) -- (f);

 % Intersection point (NOT WORKING)
 \path[name intersections={of=L1 and R1, by=B}];

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The problem I have here is, that the intersection can not be calculated. Maybe it is not working with arcs but I guess it should work. Using a full circle as a path is working but then the figure is getting bigger based on the circle (hope you get the point). Any idea suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks in advance,
Tobi

Comment: Sorry for opening that question. I don't know why I was missing the correct syntax. Thanks Heiko for the fast answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is called `name path` instead of `name` for naming a path to use it for the intersection:

```
\draw [-, name path=R1]
\path[name path=L1]
```

Comment: Oh my good. What a stupid question I asked. In my other examples I have always [name path=FOO]. Thank you very much.