# Nodes to angles and arcs

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38763/how-to-place-a-node-in-the-middle-of-an-arc)

A very common problem I come across drawing technical pictures is drawing zillions of angles.  In general, there is no nice way to put a node to an arc, so I usually have to do this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0:2cm);      %rays
\draw (0,0) -- (60:2cm);

\draw (1cm,0) arc (0:60:1cm); % angle
\draw (30:1cm+20pt) node {$\alpha$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wonder if there is a way to simplify last two commands.  Of course I could define a \newcommand{\angle}[4] which looks very awkward.  I would rather use something like that

```
\draw (1cm,0) arc (0:60:1cm) node[outarc=20pt] {$\alpha$};
```

Is it possible to define "outarc" position of the node?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture of what you would like `outarc` to do?

Comment: This is fixed in the CVS version. See this question and cjorssen's answer : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38763/how-to-place-a-node-in-the-middle-of-an-arc

Comment: @percusse a) what means CVS version?  b) Is it possible to put node by certain length away or toward the center of arc?  cjorssen's answer only concerns midway.

Comment: a) CVS version is the development version of the upcoming release so it's the beta version if you like. You can find it in [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/). b) You can also add `above=1cm` or `pos=0.3` etc. for relative positioning with respect to the arc.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I've added picture.  I want node to be put in the middle of the arc, for user-specified distance from the arc.

Comment: I just tried this in the CVS version.  It isn't *quite* as automatic as one might like.  If I did `node[midway,auto] {\(\alpha\)}` then the node is a bit above where I would want it as it chooses the south-west anchor.  To get a better position, I found that `node[midway,anchor=195]` was good (note that this is the *correct* angle).  Would an answer that only works with the CVS version of PGF be acceptable?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I have no idea how to install CVS version in the first place.  Maybe I should wait for changes to become official (after drawing thousand of angles I could make yet another hundred) and I repost the question?

Comment: Requiring a non-CVS solution is perfectly acceptable (I just installed the CVS version to try out the answer to this question, in fact) since it is often a while between official releases, but given that it is an upcoming feature you should explicitly say you'd rather not download the CVS.

Comment: @AndrewStacey If it is not too much trouble I'd prefer not to install CVS (even if I knew how).

Comment: Then use my answer in the question and add `raise=20pt` option to the decoration. So the line should read `decorate={raise=20pt,`

Comment: @percusse but then you cannot user-define distance from angle to angle, right?

Comment: Let me cook up an example.

Comment: I just had a go at this and found that my answer was exactly the same as @percusse's in the linked question - so I now think that this should be closed as a duplicate of that and percusse's answer there modified to add the "lift".

Comment: To make the lift configurable, simply define it as `.style 2 args` and pass the lift as another argument to the style.

Comment: @percusse ... which I've taken the liberty of doing

Comment: @AndrewStacey Oh, great!  Is it possible to define arcnode globally (not only for the specific tikzpicture)?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Oh thanks, perfect timing for me to get stuck on the phone :)

Comment: @Pygmalion Yes, of course!  Simply shift that whole chunk into a `\tikzset{arcnode/.style 2 args={...}}`.  Incidentally, sometimes the offset is negative.

Comment: @Pygmalion Are you now happy to have this closed as a duplicate?  (If so, I'll flag it for mod or mention it in chat to do the house-keeping quickly)

Comment: @AndrewStacey I agree.  Is it OK to start a new question when new version of TikZ becomes official?

Comment: @Pygmalion Of course - follow-up questions are always okay.  Sometimes it's appropriate to modify the original, but that's easier to determine at the time than lay down a general rule.