# Draw centered label above arc in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38763/how-to-place-a-node-in-the-middle-of-an-arc)

Following the manual where labels are positioned on curves (`\draw (0,0) .. controls (6,1) and (9,1) .. node {midway} (12,0);`), I thought this must be possible with arcs as well:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) arc node[midway]{H} (0:180:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But that doesn't compile at all.

If I use

```
\draw (1,0) arc (0:180:1) node[midway]{H};
```

then the label isn't positioned *on* (or rather above) the arc but just on the bottom line centered. I don't want to manually shift or position it.

[image: wrong]

I rather want:

[image: right]

Comment: i do not get exactly what you mean with _bottom line centered_? The last statement will put the `H` _on_ the arc, right at the middle. (So that the arc goes through the middle line in the H).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763)

Comment: @zeroth I added some screenshots

Comment: @zeroth: That's wishful thinking, but my current version  (updated recently) does not yet do that, although it appears that an upcoming version will as per the link Qrrbrbirlbel linked to..

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I read the other question but it doesn't produce the right effect here, see the first screenshot

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You might be right, I checked my pgf version (2011-11-05) and in your linked question it mentions 2012-03-01. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: @neo: I would recommend you _not_ delete the question. It will get closed as a duplicate and perhaps make it easier to find the other question in the future -- by getting to this one, depending on how they search for it.