# How can I place the theta above and midway of the arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two questions:

- How can I place the node midway,above the arc?
- in the arc the end of the arrow is black instead of orange, how can I set the color of the spike?

---

This is the latex code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,>=latex', scale=0.4 ,every
node/.style={transform shape}]
    % Draw axes
    \draw[->] (xyz cs:x=-5) -- (xyz cs:x=5) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (xyz cs:y=-5) -- (xyz cs:y=5) node[right] {$x$};
    \foreach \a in {20, 140, 250}
        \draw[draw=blue] (0, 0) -- (\a:4.5);

    \draw[draw=orange,->] (0,1) arc (90:20:1cm) node[midway,above]{$\theta$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This works as-is with PGF 3.0, can you upgrade? Edit: The output I get: http://imgur.com/iMZEMt9

Comment: Could you please update your post and make it a full working example starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`. It will help solvers to start working on it.

Comment: make sure to [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: More info here -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763/34618

Comment: @cmhughes I removed all the old packages and by following the description provided by you solved the problem. Can you add as an answer, therefore I can accept it.

Comment: @run that's great, I'm glad your problem has been resolved :) In such a situation, I'll vote to close your question as it has been resolved by updating your distribution

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it has been resolved by updating his/her distribution