# Place node in the middle on an arc during a foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, foreach, tikz-node

This question is akin to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38763/how-to-place-a-node-in-the-middle-of-an-arc), The difference being that I want to place my nodes during a foreach loop.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\thet{20};
    \def\radius{3.7};
    \foreach \ii in {1,2,...,18}
    \draw ({(\ii-1)*\thet}:\radius) arc [start angle = {(\ii-1)*\thet}, end angle ={(\ii)*\thet}, radius = \radius] node[midway] {$\theta_{\ii}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in this:

[image: theta should always be outside the circle]
I would like the thetas to always be placed outside the circle (next to the apex of the arc from which they came), but if i use a positioning keyword such as `right` or `above` it will switch all thetas in the same directions, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the node anchor to angle in the middle + 180?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\thet{20};
    \def\radius{3.7};
    \foreach \ii in {1,2,...,18}
    \draw ({(\ii-1)*\thet}:\radius) arc [start angle = {(\ii-1)*\thet}, end
    angle ={(\ii)*\thet}, radius = \radius]
    node[midway,anchor={(\ii-1/2)*\thet+180}] {$\theta_{\ii}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ;-) This works abselultly great. Sadly I have no idea why , guess I'll need to read up on anchors (-;

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Some basics of anchors are explained on p. 233 of the pgfmanual, i.e. one can replace `anchor=south` by `anchor=-90` and so on, and then other numbers are just a generalization thereof.

Comment: Yup, I see now. It was even written on p. 228: "Unfortunately, while perfectly logical, it is often rather counter-intuitive that in order to place a node above
a given point, you need to specify the south anchor" So it makes sense now ;-) Thanks a lot for the help.