# TikZ: Robust and automated creation of signal-flow graph (parallel form)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikz-matrix, tikz-chains

Following up on [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569856/2288), I would like to know how I can automatically and robustly create the parallel form of a signal-flow diagram for the following without manual drawing of the lines/nodes:

Consider a transfer function without repeated poles

[image]

Each term is a ﬁrst-order subsystem with R(s) as the input, and the output `C(s)` can be considered the sum of the three terms

[image]

Therefore, this leads to the following **desired** parallel form of the signal-flow diagram

[image]

My questions about my code below are:

1- why doesn't `foreach` work in my code?

2- How to fine-tune the position of `amark` labels to make them move away a bit from the curved lines?

3- How can I robustly automate the process of drawing the diagram without the manual drawing of lines/nodes?

4- Is there a more simplified code of the code below using `tikz-cd`, `matrix of nodes`, or `chains`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,positioning,arrows.meta,matrix}
\newif\iflabrev
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 15mm and 15mm, 
        relative = false,
        label revd/.is if = labrev,
        label revd/.default = true,
        amark/.style = {
            decoration={             
                markings,   
                mark=at position {0.5} with { 
                    \arrow{stealth},
                    \iflabrev \node[below] {#1};\else \node[above] {#1};\fi
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate}
        },
    terminal/.style 2 args={draw,alias=ln,circle,inner sep=2pt,label={#1:#2}},
        ]
        \path
        node[terminal={left}{$R(s)$}] (R) {}
        node[above right=of R, terminal={}{}] (sX-1) {}
        node[right=of sX-1, terminal={}{}] (X-1) {}
        node[right=of R, terminal={}{}] (sX-2) {}
        node[right=of sX-2, terminal={}{}] (X-2) {}
        node[right=of X-2, terminal={right}{$C(s)$}] (C) {}
        node[below right=of R, terminal={}{}] (sX-3) {}
        node[right=of sX-3, terminal={}{}] (X-3) {}
        ;
        %
        \foreach \X in {1,...,3}{
            (sX-\X) edge[amark=1/s] (X-\X)
        };
    \path (R) edge[out=90,in=180,amark=12] (sX-1) (X-1) edge[out=-90,in=-90,amark=-2] (sX-1) edge[out=0,in=90,amark=1] (C);
    \path (R) edge[amark=-24] (sX-2) (X-2) edge[out=-90,in=-90,amark=-3] (sX-2) edge[amark=1] (C);
    \path (R) edge[out=-90,in=180,amark=12,label revd] (sX-3) (X-3) edge[out=-90,in=-90,amark=-4] (sX-3) edge[out=0,in=-90,amark=1,label revd] (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just some quick fixes.

1. `foreach` does not work because there is no `\path` command.
2. You can use an `edge label` to achieve an arguably better positioning.

Items 3 and 4 would require more thought. But this would make more sense if it was clear what the overall structure of these diagrams is. This would allow one to gauge which strategy may be the most appropriate one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,positioning,arrows.meta,matrix}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Dim}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmath@count=0\relax
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{#1}%
    \pgfutil@for\pgfutil@tmpa:={\pgfutil@tmpb}\do{%
      \advance\pgfmath@count by1\relax}%
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\the\pgfmath@count}% 
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult% 
  \endgroup}  
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 15mm and 15mm, 
        relative = false,
        amark/.style = {
            decoration={             
                markings,   
                mark=at position {0.5} with { 
                    \arrow{stealth},
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate},
            edge label={#1}
        },
        amark'/.style = {
            decoration={             
                markings,   
                mark=at position {0.5} with { 
                    \arrow{stealth},
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate},
            edge label'={#1}
        },
    terminal/.style 2 args={draw,alias=ln,circle,inner sep=2pt},
        ]
        % input
        \def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4}
        %\def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4,5/-7}
        %\def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4,5/-7,3/-3}
        % number of insertion
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{Dim("\GraphInput")}
        % local bounding box is a trick that all distances derive from node distance
        \path[local bounding box=graph] 
         foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in \GraphInput {
         % draw the inner nodes in a loop
          \ifnum\Z=1
          node[terminal] (sX-\Z){} node[right=of sX-\Z,terminal] (X-\Z){}
          \else
          node[terminal,below=of sX-\the\numexpr\Z-1] (sX-\Z){} 
          node[right=of sX-\Z,terminal] (X-\Z){}
          \fi
        }
        % draw R and S nodes
        node[left=of graph,terminal,label=left:{$R(s)$}] (R){}
        node[right=of graph,terminal,label=right:{$C(s)$}] (C){}
        % loop for connections
        foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in \GraphInput {
        % bug in pgf, out does not get parsed properly
        [/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\myout}{90-(\Z-1)*180/(\mydim-1)}]
        (sX-\Z) edge[amark={$1/s$}] (X-\Z)
        (X-\Z) edge[amark'={$\Y$},out=-90,in=-90] (sX-\Z)
        \ifnum\Z>\numexpr\mydim/2
         (R) edge[amark'={$\X$},out=\myout,in=180] (sX-\Z)
         (X-\Z) edge[amark'={$1$},out=0,in=180-\myout] (C)
        \else
         (R) edge[amark={$\X$},out=\myout,in=180] (sX-\Z)
         (X-\Z) edge[amark={$1$},out=0,in=180-\myout] (C)
        \fi
        };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is a routine that draws the graph from some input like

```
\def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4}
```

I tried to add some explanations. Unfortunately there is also a pgf issue with the parsing of `in` and `out` in edges. This code also places the edge labels more tightly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,positioning,arrows.meta,matrix}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Dim}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmath@count=0\relax
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{#1}%
    \pgfutil@for\pgfutil@tmpa:={\pgfutil@tmpb}\do{%
      \advance\pgfmath@count by1\relax}%
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\the\pgfmath@count}% 
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult% 
  \endgroup}  
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 15mm and 15mm, 
        relative = false,
        amark/.style = {
            decoration={             
                markings,   
                mark=at position {0.5} with { 
                    \arrow{stealth},
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate},
            nodes={inner xsep=0pt},
            edge label={#1}
        },
        amark'/.style = {
            decoration={             
                markings,   
                mark=at position {0.5} with { 
                    \arrow{stealth},
                }
            },
            postaction={decorate},
            nodes={inner xsep=0pt},
            edge label'={#1}
        },
    terminal/.style 2 args={draw,alias=ln,circle,inner sep=2pt},
        ]
        % input
        %\def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4}
        \def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4,5/-7}
        % number of insertions
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{Dim("\GraphInput")}
        % local bounding box is a trick that all distances derive from node distance
        \path[local bounding box=graph] 
         foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in \GraphInput {
         % draw the inner nodes in a loop
          \ifnum\Z=1
          node[terminal] (sX-\Z){} node[right=of sX-\Z,terminal] (X-\Z){}
          \else
          node[terminal,below=of sX-\the\numexpr\Z-1] (sX-\Z){} 
          node[right=of sX-\Z,terminal] (X-\Z){}
          \fi
        }
        % draw R and S nodes
        node[left=of graph,terminal,label=left:{$R(s)$}] (R){}
        node[right=of graph,terminal,label=right:{$C(s)$}] (C){}
        % loop for connections
        foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in \GraphInput {
        % bug in pgf, out does not get parsed properly
        [/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\myout}{90-(\Z-1)*180/(\mydim-1)}]
        (sX-\Z) edge[amark={$1/s$}] (X-\Z)
        (X-\Z) edge[amark'={$\Y$},out=-90,in=-90] (sX-\Z)
        \ifnum\Z>\numexpr\mydim/2
         (R) edge[amark'={$\X$},out=\myout,in=180] (sX-\Z)
         (X-\Z) edge[amark'={$1$},out=0,in=180-\myout] (C)
        \else
         (R) edge[amark={$\X$},out=\myout,in=180] (sX-\Z)
         (X-\Z) edge[amark={$1$},out=0,in=180-\myout] (C)
        \fi
        };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to have an automatic/robust way to do it like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569862/2288) by just providing the numerators and denominators of each term without having to manually place the nodes and draw the lines regardless the number of the terms?

Comment: @Diaa It certainly is if it is clear what the structure of the input is. I take that the number of factors is variable, i.e. not necessarily equal to 3. Is that right? And the `1` on the arrows on the right seem to be redundant, or is there a possibility they change, and if so, how?

Comment: The labels of the right arrows are always ones. The number of the branches/terms is problem-dependent and doesn't have to be three. You expect an input from me to be the signed numerical numerator and the signed number added/subtracted to/from S in the denominator of each term.

Comment: BTW, why do you have amark' and amark'? Aren't they the same?

Comment: @Diaa I added such a routine. `amark` and `amark'` are distinguished by `edge label` vs `edge label'`, which swaps the position of the edge label.

Comment: When having `\def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4,5/-7}` the output looks weird https://i.ibb.co/sy26sNY/image.png instead of being symmetric with two parallel branches on each side of the centerlne connecting `R(s)` and `C(s)`. Additionally, this `\def\GraphInput{12/-2,-24/-3,12/-4,5/-7,3/-3}` should have one middle straight (of `12/-4`) branch with two symmetrical ones on each side **not** like this https://i.ibb.co/JBgp23K/image.png

Comment: @Diaa Yes, you are right. Sorry about this. I shouldn't have used the function `dim` (which got advertised recently on this site...)  but should have checked carefully. Fixed it.

Comment: One final question please: is it possible to make the arrow label of `-24` not overlap the neighbor branch as shown here https://i.ibb.co/Vx2hKJ9/image.png?

Comment: I mean is it possible to add some conditional `ifnum\X=-24` then another label option is activated to make separation around the label be reduced or move it closer to its respective branch?

Comment: In this case I would just place the edge labels more closely. I added that to the second code.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tiz-cd` package (which is designed to draw such diagrams), you will avoid your problems. Code is relative simple and clear, and shorter:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}
\newif\iflabrev

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
    cells={nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=2pt}},
    every arrow/.append style = {decoration={markings, 
                                             mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}},
                                 postaction={decorate}, -
                                },
    every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize}                
                ]
    & \ar[r,"1/s"]
            & \ar[l,"-2",bend left=60]
              \ar[rd,"1",bend left]
                    &                       \\
|[label=left:R(s)]| 
 \ar[ru,"12",bend left] 
 \ar[rd,"12",bend right]
 \ar[r,"-24"]       
    & 
      \ar[r,"1/s"]
            & \ar[l,"-3", bend left=60]
              \ar[r,"1"]
                    & |[label=right:C(s)]|  \\
    & \ar[r,"1/s"]
            & \ar[l,"-4",bend left=60]
              \ar[ru,"1",bend right]
                    &                       \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Note, if you like to change distances between node, than you only need to add to `tikzcd` options:

```
column sep=<desired distance between columns>,
row sep=<desired distance between rows>,
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to have an automatic/robust way to do it like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569862/2288) by just providing the numerators and denominators of each term without having to manually place the nodes and draw the lines regardless the number of the terms?