# TikZ:How to draw the pump schematic drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here [My first Tikz picture: help on positioning and suggestions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53930/my-first-tikz-picture-help-on-positioning-and-suggestions) we have a nice drawing similar to this image.

[image]

> How to draw the pump element in the above image?
>   How to draw the anticlock arrow?

Like turbine is it possible to make  `\tikzset` for pump

```
\tikzset{turb/.style={draw,trapezium,shape border rotate=90,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium stretches=true,trapezium angle=80,on grid,below right= of evaporatore}}
```

---

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings,patterns,calc,fit,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',auto,inner sep=2mm,node distance=2cm and 3cm]

%set styles for the axis between turbine and pump and for the boxes

\tikzset{box1/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,rectangle,thick}}
\tikzset{deco/.style={decoration={markings,
                       mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},
                       postaction={decorate}}}
\tikzset{turb/.style={draw,trapezium,shape border rotate=90,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium stretches=true,trapezium angle=80,on grid,below right= of evaporatore}}   

% draw nodes
\node[box1] (evaporatore)  {Boiler};
\node[turb] (turbina) {Turbine};
\node[box1,on grid,below left=of turbina] (condensatore){Condenser};
%\node[draw,circle,on grid,below left= of evaporatore] (pompa) {Pump};
\node[draw,circle,on grid,below left= of evaporatore] (pompa) {Pump}; 
\draw (pompa.70) |- ++(2.5mm,5mm) coordinate (mid)  -| (pompa.east);


\begin{scope}[>=triangle 45]
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (evaporatore)                -| (turbina.top right corner);
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (turbina.bottom left corner) |- (condensatore);
 \draw [deco=0.4]  (condensatore)               -| (pompa);
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (mid)                      |- (evaporatore);
 \end{scope}

%draw the "shaft"

\path(pompa) to node[]{shaft} (turbina);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] ($(pompa.east)+(0,-3pt)$) rectangle ($(turbina.west)+(0,3pt)$);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] ($(turbina.east)+(0,-3pt)$) rectangle ++(1,6pt);
\draw[->] (25:1) arc (10:320:0.2cm and 0.75cm) ;
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Pump element changed (thanks to percusse).
>   Instead of node, coordinate is used...
>   \draw (pompa.70) |- ++(2.5mm,5mm) coordinate (mid)  -| (pompa.east);

[image]

Comment: Replace the line with `\draw (p.70) |- ++(2mm,5mm) node (pompaout){} -| (p.east);` and use `(pompaout)` instead for the pump output.

Comment: node (pompaout){} : empty node always reserve some space.

Comment: You are right, make it a coordinate. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you percusse... Help me in palcing the anticlock arrow. (red color in the image)

Comment: You get a fine anticlock arrow with : `\draw[->] (evaporatore.north) arc (25:335:0.2cm and 0.8cm) ;    `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-0.4) rectangle (2,0.4);
\draw[->] (25:1) arc (30:320:0.2cm and 0.75cm) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with your example**

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings,patterns,calc,fit,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',auto,inner sep=2mm,node distance=2cm and 3cm]

%set styles for the axis between turbine and pump and for the boxes

\tikzset{box1/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,rectangle,thick}}
\tikzset{deco/.style={decoration={markings,
                       mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},
                       postaction={decorate}}}
\tikzset{turb/.style={draw,trapezium,shape border rotate=90,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium stretches=true,trapezium angle=80,on grid,below right= of evaporatore}}   

% draw nodes
\node[box1] (evaporatore)  {Boiler};
\node[turb] (turbina) {Turbine};
\node[box1,on grid,below left=of turbina] (condensatore){Condenser};
%\node[draw,circle,on grid,below left= of evaporatore] (pompa) {Pump};
\node[draw,circle,on grid,below left= of evaporatore] (pompa) {Pump}; 
\draw (pompa.70) |- ++(2.5mm,5mm) coordinate (mid)  -| (pompa.east);


\begin{scope}[>=triangle 45]
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (evaporatore)                -| (turbina.top right corner);
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (turbina.bottom left corner) |- (condensatore);
 \draw [deco=0.4]  (condensatore)               -| (pompa);
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (mid)                      |- (evaporatore);
 \end{scope}

%draw the "shaft"

\path(pompa) to node[]{shaft} (turbina);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] ($(pompa.east)+(0,-3pt)$) rectangle ($(turbina.west)+(0,3pt)$);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] ($(turbina.east)+(0,-3pt)$) rectangle ++(1,6pt);
\draw[->] ([shift={(0.75,3pt)}]turbina.east) arc (10:350:0.2cm and {3pt/sin(10)}) ; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Explanations for the last arrow**

> You need to determine the origin point. The point of reference here is `turbina.east`.

You can use `calc` library or the old method with `shift` as given below

> `($ (turbina.east)+(0.75,3pt)$)` or `([shift={(0.75,3pt)}]turbina.east)`

The origin point is on the top of the last rectangle. Then you need to choice the start angle (see the good answer from PolGab to understand how to get the end angle).

Comment: I want arc on this...\draw[pattern=north east lines] ($(turbina.east)+(0,-3pt)$) rectangle ++(1,6pt);

Comment: @sandu I made an update with this request in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The arrow is simply a long arc :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (15:2.5mm) arc (15:345:2.5mm and 7.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives

[image]

also the pump is a node with extension:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (p) {Pump}; 
\draw (p.70) |- ++(1mm,5mm) -| (p.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

here is an example with PSTricks. The code (http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery) can be run with `xelatex` to get directly a pdf output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of angles and radii of arc is feasible if the height of the node is fixed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \he in {1cm,1.3cm}
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [minimum width=2cm,minimum height=\he,draw] (a){Test};
    \foreach \angle in {25,30,35} {
      \draw[-stealth]
      (a.north)
      arc[start angle=\angle,end angle=360-\angle,x radius=\he/4,y radius=\he/sin(\angle)/2]
      ;
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]